# AWS-Logs, ElasticSearch : Specific logs not showing up in ElasticSearch, working only for select logs

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-cloudwatch

I am streaming AWSLogs to CLoudwatch and from there, I am streaming it on ElasticSearch domain. I can see in the overview, that I have a heck number of searchable documents, but I am not able to find the documents from many different log-streams when I am searching them in Kibana. It's working only for 2-3 out of 35 log streams. I can see all streams in CloudWatch logs, and on the right side, can also see that I am streaming to ElasticSearch instance. I will explain how I am doing it, maybe some idea what am I doing wrong. Thank you.

Installed AWSLogs service from [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/QuickStartEC2Instance.html)
Commands :

```
curl https://s3.amazonaws.com/aws-cloudwatch/downloads/latest/awslogs-agent-setup.py -O
sudo python ./awslogs-agent-setup.py --region OUR_REGION
```

Once that's done, I added in `/var/awslogs/etc/awslogs.conf` my log files in such manner :

```
[/var/www/html/var/log/exception.log]
datetime_format = %d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S
file = /var/www/html/var/log/exception.log
buffer_duration = 5000
log_stream_name = staging.1c.APP_NAME.exception.log
initial_position = end_of_file
log_group_name = staging.1c.APP_NAME.exception.log
```

After that, I logged into Kibana, and in index-patterns, defined an index-pattern as `cwl-*`.

Comment: Why not simply leveraging [FunctionBeat](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/functionbeat/current/functionbeat-overview.html)?

Comment: @Val : We have a lot of instances already sending data to cloudwatch directly.... Looking to fix this rather than change the entire architecture.... Any ideas what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I understand. Do you see anything worthy in `/var/log/awslogs.log` ? Also can you explain how you're streaming those logs to ES? Are you using the AWS Elasticsearch managed service?

Comment: @Val : I am using awslogs agent to send logs to cloudwatch-logs... and from cloudwatch-logs I am selecting actions and "Stream ES service". I already have a domain configured.... it has 55mb of data in one of the cwl-* index....but I just can't see the data in discover.

Comment: @Val : I can see in logs that data is getting successfully pushed....

Comment: Got it, so we're talking about the managed ES service! In your index pattern, did you pick a date field? if yes, can you make sure that your period picker (top right) is selecting an appropriate period?

Comment: @Val :Selected for an entire month.... Should we move to chat? Once it's finalized, maybe u can add an answer then. Thanks a lot. :-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199608/discussion-between-we-are-borg-and-val).

Comment: @Val : Can u please check chat.. thanks. :-)